# How to package a jar file along with reference files?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, reference

Using eclipse, exporting a runnable jar file is pretty simple when I'm only using the application on my computer. Any files that the program is using (sprite sheets, audio tracks, etc.) only exist on my computer, so sending solely the jar to another machine won't work.

What is the easiest way to package a jar along with all the necessary files so that I could run the program on any machine?

Answer (score 1):

I see from your tags that you are working in Eclipse. I am not sure if this method will work in other IDEs and I don't think it'll work at all if you're doing everything manually (it relies on the compiler automatically copying resources over to the `bin` folder.

The simplest way (at least what I use) is to define another sourcefolder (I like `res`).

Then you can just add packages to this source folder and dump the relevant images. Then rebuild your project.

Finally, you can use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("package/path/file_name.whatever");` to get your files.

After an export as `jar`, it should work, even on other machines.

Comment: Which package should you use here? Isn't the res folder usually created outside of any package?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I generally put them in my `com.whatever.ui` package within the res folder. So from the project root it would be `<project root>/res/com/whatever/ui`. I don't know what the generally accepted way is for this. You could just dump the files into `res` and refer to them as `file_name.whatever` if you wanted to instead...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require the other files to be actual files on the file system (which means you *can't use `File`, `FileInputStream`, etc*) then you can use the resource system. If you put them inside the JAR, you can access them like this:

```
InputStream fileStream = SomeClassInYourJarFile.class
                                            .getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file.png");
```

This example would give you an `InputStream` reading from the `/path/to/file.png` entry in your JAR file - that is, the "file.png" file inside a folder "to" inside a folder "path".

This does not *require* the files to be in a JAR file - it can load them from wherever your .class files are stored, JAR or not. If you put them in your source folder, Eclipse will automatically copy them to that place - so the above line would also work if you had a package `path.to` containing a file called `file.png`.

Comment: I'm confused what the InputStream actually is and how it's used. Is it the actual File? If not, how do you convert it to a File?

Comment: @Dan an InputStream is "something you can read from". Which might be an actual file, or an entry in a JAR (which is *impossible* to convert to a `File`, because it's not a file - unless your program copies it to a file which would defeat the point of packing things inside your JAR)

Comment: @Dan there are InputStreams from files (`FileInputStream`), JAR entries, network connections, byte arrays, etc. Basically anything you might ever want to read data from.

Comment: So what would it be valid to try and create a BufferedImage by reading from an InputStream? When I try to create it as "ImageIO.read(stream)" (where stream is the name of the InputStream), I get an error saying that input is null.

Comment: @Dan If you've done much Java programming, you should know that if something is null, it's because of where it came from and not because of how you use it. Specifically `getResourceAsStream` must be returning null (or you forgot to actually call it). It returns null if it can't find the resource - what path are you passing to it, where is the actual file on your hard drive (before it goes in the JAR), and where are your .class files and .java files?

Comment: Ok, so it's unable to find the file? In eclipse, I just right clicked the project folder and made a new resource folder (I'm assuming this is part of the build path). The image is in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68693/discussion-between-immibis-and-dan).